# How to get both Data Table and Chart on the same slide

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint

I have a code in Excel VBA that will export both my charts and data tables to PowerPoint, but I can't seem to get them both on the same slides (so chart above data table in PowerPoint). Please help.

```
Sub ExportMultipleChartsToPowerPoint_FullWorkbook3()   
    'Declare PowerPoint Object Variables
    Dim PPTApp As PowerPoint.Application
    Dim PPTPres As PowerPoint.Presentation
    Dim PPTSlide As PowerPoint.Slide
    Dim PPTShape As PowerPoint.Shape
    Dim PPTShapeRng As PowerPoint.ShapeRange
    Dim ShpCnt As Integer

    'Declare Excel Object Variables
    Dim Chrt As ChartObject
    Dim Wrksht As Worksheet
    Dim SldIndex As Integer
    Dim ExcRng As Range
    Dim RngArray As Variant

    'Create a new instance of PowerPoint
    Set PPTApp = New PowerPoint.Application
    PPTApp.Visible = True

    'Create a new Presentation within the Application
    Set PPTPres = PPTApp.Presentations.Add

    'Create an Index Handler for slide creation
    SldIndex = 1

    'For Errors
    On Error Resume Next

    'Look through all of the Worksheets in the ACTIVE WORKBOOK
    For Each Wrksht In Worksheets
        'Loop through all the Chart Objects on the ACTIVESHEET
        For Each Chrt In Wrksht.ChartObjects      
            'Copy the chart
            Chrt.Copy

            'Tell Macro to wait for ONE SECOND
            Application.Wait Now + #12:00:01 AM#

            'Create a new slide, set the layout to blank, and paste the chart
            Set PPTSlide = PPTPres.Slides.Add(SldIndex, ppLayoutTitleOnly)
            PPTSlide.Shapes.PasteSpecial DataType:=ppPasteJPG

            'Add Text to Slide Title and format
            PPTSlide.Shapes(1).TextFrame.TextRange = "X008 - CARS all bookings consultant YR details"

            'Count the number of shapes on my slide
            ShpCnt = PPTSlide.Shapes.Count

            'Set a reference to the shape I want to manipulate
            Set PPTShapeRng = PPTSlide.Shapes.Range(Array(ShpCnt))

            'Set Dimension of my shape range
            With PPTShapeRng
                .Height = 240
                .Width = 660
                .Top = 135
                .Align msoAlignCenters, True
            End With

            'Increment our slide index
            SldIndex = SldIndex + 1
        Next Chrt
    Next Wrksht

    'Create an array that has the references to the ranges I want to export
    RngArray = Array(Worksheets("Global Results").Range("A30:H37"), Worksheets("G-FPO-GC").Range("A30:H37"), Worksheets("G-FPO-GCA").Range("A30:H37"), Worksheets("G-FPO-GCE").Range("A30:H37"), Worksheets("G-FPO-GCG").Range("A30:H37"), Worksheets("G-FPO-GCN").Range("A30:H37"), Worksheets("G-FPO-GCO").Range("A30:H37"))

    'Loop through this array, copy the range, and create a new slide, and then paste the range in the slide
    For x = LBound(RngArray) To UBound(RngArray)
        'Set a reference to the range we want to export
        Set ExcRng = RngArray(x)

        'Copy the range
        ExcRng.Copy

        'Create a new slide in the presentation
        Set PPTSlide = PPTPres.Slides.Add(x + 1, ppLayoutTitleOnly)

        'Paste the range in the slide
        PPTApp.ActiveWindow.ViewType = ppViewNormal
        PPTSlide.Shapes.PasteSpecial DataType:=ppPasteEnhancedMetafile

        'Count the number of shapes on my slide
        ShpCnt = PPTSlide.Shapes.Count

        'Set a reference to the shape I want to manipulate
        Set PPTShapeRng = PPTSlide.Shapes.Range(Array(ShpCnt))

        'Set the dimensions of my shaperange
        With PPTShapeRng
            .Align msoAlignCenters, True
            .Left = 80
            .Top = 430
            .Height = 100
        End With
    Next x
End Sub
```

Every now and then, there will be another error message that says there's something wrong with my Chrt.Copy and I have no idea why

Comment: What is the error message and in which line do you get it? You might benefit from reading 
[Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/284237/3219613) • Remove `On Error Resume Next` to see your error messages. This line does not stop errors, it just hides the messages but the errors still occur. If you cannot see the errors you cannot fix them, if you don't fix them your code does not work.

Comment: The error message says "Slide (unknown member): Object does not exist" and highlights my "Chrt.Copy". Sometimes, if I just go through my Workbook then re-run the code, it works fine. I don't know if this has something to do with VBA or Excel. I know how "On Error Resume Next" works, but it was the only way to get the code to run at all. I know the risks of using it, but I have been trying to fix this error for about 6 hours so forgive me for not "asking an actual question".

Comment: For now, just ignore the error statement. I know that this may be blasphemous in the coding community but for now, the code works. Please, oh god please, can someone help me just combine my 2 codes into 1 so that both the data table and corresponding charts appear on the same slide

Comment: *"for now, the code works."* You cannot tell if your code works properly or not with a `On Error Resume Next` in it having no proper error handling! If you say *"but it was the only way to get the code to run at all."* then this means there are errors in your code that you have to fix. Your code is **not** running properly. • So the only way to solve this is starting with removing `On Error Resume Next` and start fixing the first error you get (which is it?). • The way you use`On Error Resume Next` is like telling VBA *"Yes, I know there are errors, but shut the f… up!"* that cannot work.